# adding username and password Token to WSSecurity web service call (.net client)

Tags: web-services, credentials, soapheader

Hey there code warriors and stack exchangers.

I have been trying in vain to set credentials for a web service.  I wrote the webservice in Websphere (java ee) and it requires a username and password in the header for any of the services to be called.  I can run it fine in SOAP UI, but I need to be able to hit it from a .net web client.

So far I have tried setting the credentials like so...

```
dlc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "idiotCreds";
dlc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "someWhackyPWD";
```

And so far I have just recieved this exception

```
security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS6500E: There is no caller identity candidate that can be used to login. ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@42304230
```

Which I am guessing is telling me that there are no credentials being set...
Even though I set the client credentials.  Do I need to create and add a soap header manually here?  I thought that was supposed to be handled by that client object?  Any ideas fellas?  Thanks

Comment: Its starting to look like WCF can't do this?  That is really disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question and answer in this SO thread will provide those who seek answers with the solutions they need.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12159837/729820